# Simple Angular 2 Cordova app not working on android emulator

Tags: cordova, angular, android-emulator

I'm developing on **windows 10** using **VS code**, I have **android studio** setup with **android emulator nexus 5 API 24**

I used **angular-cli** to create a new angular 2 app:

```
 ng new angular2-cordova-test
```

In the project folder I used **Cordova cli** to create a new Cordova project:

```
 cordova create cordova com.example.cordova cordova
 cordova platform add android --save
 cordova build
```

From **root** directory I built the angular 2 app into the **Cordova** `www` directory

```
 ng build --prod --output-path=cordova/www/
```

When I run app from `cordova` directory into emulator:

```
 cordova emulate android
```

I got `Loading...` in the emulator, and app in **not working**

[Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK7Zd.png)

I think this has something to do with *ES6* and emulator *webview*

how can I fix this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I asked this question rephrased here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470766/angular-2-and-cordova

which is closed for weired reasons!! so the answer there is in the comments

The problem was very trivial, the HTML formed by the angular 2 project contained:

`<base href="/">`

this is what caused the problem, just remove it

also in the way to solve the problem I learned how to:

- debug the app with chrome dev tools on emulator
- debug the app with chrome dev tools on my phone
- create signed APKs

it was a good experiment

**update:**

after getting into a situation of building angular + cordova + routing, **Parth Ghiya**'s hint is a **must**

I changed the meta tag to `<base href=".">` and everything including routing worked just fine

Comment: Great...  correct the problem fix replacing `<base href="/">` for `<base href=".">`

Answer (score 3):

Just use

if u remove the base href then your routes wont work in angular 2.

if u want to build,
do

```
ng build --prod --base-href .
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this to set the base:  `<base href="./">`. This worked for me. But you can also use `<base href="file:///android_asset/www/" />` for android.

Finally i have a fully helpful suggestion to use the Chrome remote debugger to debug your mobile app. The console it tells everything.